# problem while using sapply to impute date

Tags: r

I have a date valuable, and I need to substract the date, month, year info outand then build the new day valuable. when there is not valid input, use 1 in place.

Here is the data and the codes I used. but i found my outcome has error. And I don't know what I did wrong. Can someone help me on this?

The error was marked in read.

[image]

```
## Data
Date<-c("UN UNK 2017","UN UNK 2017","UN UNK 2017","UN UNK 2017","10 Dec 2016","12 Sep 2016","30 Jun 2016","UN UNK 2016","UN UNK 2016","un UNK 2016","un UNK 2016","08 Jan 2016","02 Jan 2016","11 Dec 2015","UN Nov 2015","15 Oct 2015","12 Oct 2015","24 Sep 2015","un Sep 2015","28 Aug 2015","un Jul 2015")

Sample.data <- data.frame(Date)

## Impute dates
impute_dates <- function(x)
{
  years  <- gsub("^.*?(\\d{4}).*?$", "\\1", x)
  years  <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(years))
  months <- match(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 2), month.abb)
  months[is.na(months)] <- 1
  days <- match(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 1), 1:31)
  days[is.na(days)] <- 1
  data.frame(years, months, days)
  as.Date(paste(years, months, days, sep = "-"))
}

Sample.data$Date_OK <-impute_dates(Sample.data$Date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `debug(impute_dates)`, the run it and step through until it calculates `days`.
2. Notice that `sapply(...)` is returning `"08"`, not `"8"`.

   ```r
   sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 1)
   #  [1] "UN" "UN" "UN" "UN" "10" "12" "30" "UN" "UN" "un" "un" "08" "02" "11" "UN" "15" "12" "24" "un" "28" "un"
   ```

   Realize that since one of the arguments of `match` is `character`, then the other is converted to it, so `match(sapply(...), 1:31)` is really using `as.character(1:31)`, which includes `"8"`, not `"08"`.

Options:

1. pre-strip leading 0s before matching it:

   ```r
   gsub("^0", "", sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 1))
   #  [1] "UN" "UN" "UN" "UN" "10" "12" "30" "UN" "UN" "un" "un" "8"  "2"  "11" "UN" "15" "12" "24" "un" "28" "un"
   ### 'cbind' for demonstration only
   days <- match(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 1), 1:31)
   days2 <- match(gsub("^0", "", sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 1)), 1:31)
   cbind(Sample.data, months, days, days2)
   #           Date    Date_OK months days days2
   # 1  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 2  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 3  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 4  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 5  10 Dec 2016 2016-12-10     12   10    10
   # 6  12 Sep 2016 2016-09-12      9   12    12
   # 7  30 Jun 2016 2016-06-30      6   30    30
   # 8  UN UNK 2016 2016-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 9  UN UNK 2016 2016-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 10 un UNK 2016 2016-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 11 un UNK 2016 2016-01-01      1   NA    NA
   # 12 08 Jan 2016 2016-01-01      1   NA     8  # <--- fixed!
   # 13 02 Jan 2016 2016-01-01      1   NA     2  # <---
   # 14 11 Dec 2015 2015-12-11     12   11    11
   # 15 UN Nov 2015 2015-11-01     11   NA    NA
   # 16 15 Oct 2015 2015-10-15     10   15    15
   # 17 12 Oct 2015 2015-10-12     10   12    12
   # 18 24 Sep 2015 2015-09-24      9   24    24
   # 19 un Sep 2015 2015-09-01      9   NA    NA
   # 20 28 Aug 2015 2015-08-28      8   28    28
   # 21 un Jul 2015 2015-07-01      7   NA    NA
   ```
2. convert to an integer using `suppressWarnings(as.integer(...))`, as @Duck suggests in that answer. The suppression is justified because the leading `"UN"` is going to produce warnings that we expect (and therefore don't need to see).
3. Preemptively replace `"UN"` and `"UNK"` with the numbers you need:

   ```r
   as.Date(
     gsub("\\bUN\\b", "01", 
          gsub("\\bUNK\\b", "Jan", Sample.data$Date, ignore.case = TRUE),
          ignore.case = TRUE),
     format = "%d %b %Y")
   #  [1] "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2016-12-10" "2016-09-12" "2016-06-30" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
   # [10] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-08" "2016-01-02" "2015-12-11" "2015-11-01" "2015-10-15" "2015-10-12" "2015-09-24"
   # [19] "2015-09-01" "2015-08-28" "2015-07-01"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this change on your function. The issue was on the `sapply()` for obtaining days. As the values were obtained as characters (`02`,`08`) they did not match with the day scale of `1:31`. Using `as.numeric()` gives those values the proper format. Here the code:

```
#Function
impute_dates <- function(x)
{
  years  <- gsub("^.*?(\\d{4}).*?$", "\\1", x)
  years  <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(years))
  months <- match(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 2), month.abb)
  months[is.na(months)] <- 1
  days <- suppressWarnings(match(as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "),
                                                   `[`, 1)), 1:31))
  days[is.na(days)] <- 1
  y <- as.Date(paste(years, months, days, sep = "-"))
  return(y)
}
#Apply
Sample.data$Date_OK <-impute_dates(Sample.data$Date)
```

Output:

```
Sample.data
          Date    Date_OK
1  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01
2  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01
3  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01
4  UN UNK 2017 2017-01-01
5  10 Dec 2016 2016-12-10
6  12 Sep 2016 2016-09-12
7  30 Jun 2016 2016-06-30
8  UN UNK 2016 2016-01-01
9  UN UNK 2016 2016-01-01
10 un UNK 2016 2016-01-01
11 un UNK 2016 2016-01-01
12 08 Jan 2016 2016-01-08
13 02 Jan 2016 2016-01-02
14 11 Dec 2015 2015-12-11
15 UN Nov 2015 2015-11-01
16 15 Oct 2015 2015-10-15
17 12 Oct 2015 2015-10-12
18 24 Sep 2015 2015-09-24
19 un Sep 2015 2015-09-01
20 28 Aug 2015 2015-08-28
21 un Jul 2015 2015-07-01
```